# how do i add icon / badge in push notification (fcm) from a cloud function js firebase - Angular

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, badge

Notifications are sent correctly but I don't know how to modify this ...
I tried a url to a 32x32 image in storage (firebase) and it didn't work either.
From a path to assets and neither ...

[image]

cloud functions

```
   const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: notificacion.titulo,
 badge: '../src/assets/icons/dragon.png', //?????????
        icon: notificacion.photoURL,
      },
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Notification payload support](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#:%7E:text=Table%202c.%20Web%20(JavaScript)%20%E2%80%94%20keys%20for%20notification%20messages), `badge` is not one of the supported notification payload keys for web.